# SQL to display last inserted rows

Tags: sql

How To get the Last inserted three records from the table.
For example I have seven values i want to display last three inserted values

```
s.No    name
1     1karthik
2     2shakti
3     3yuva
4     4dilli
5     5babu
6     6bombay
7     7hills
```

I want to display last three inserted rows dynamically

Comment: What RDBMS? The syntax is different depending on whether it's MySQL, Oracle, SQL-Server, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select top 3 * from YourTable order by [S. No] desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle:
`select * from YourTable where rownum<=3 order by S.No;`

Comment: Well then give me some more info. What error are you seeing? What database are you even using?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server:

If `[s.No]` is an `IDENTITY` column then you can use `TOP` and `ORDER BY`. Otherwise you are out of luck.

```
SELECT TOP 3 [s.No], [name]
FROM [table]
ORDER BY [s.No] DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3

-- mysql